# Get all users and contacts from a group in Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, directoryentry

I have been searching around for a solution on getting both users and contacts from a group in Active Directory, but cant find one.

I understand that I cant get contacts the same way as users because they are not security principals?

I use this code to get all users in my group, is it possible to extend this to retrieve name, and mobile number from contacts? Or do I need to write something new?

```
            var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MY_DOMAIN");
            using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher())
            {
                var groupName = "MY_GROUP";
                var sp = new GroupPrincipal(context, groupName);
                searcher.QueryFilter = sp;
                var group = searcher.FindOne() as GroupPrincipal;

                if (group == null)
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Group Name: {0}", groupName);

                foreach (var f in group.GetMembers())
                {
                    var principal = f as UserPrincipal;

                    if (principal == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(principal.Name))
                        continue;

                    DirectoryEntry entry = (principal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry);
                    DirectorySearcher entrySearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
                    entrySearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mobile");
                    entrySearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
                    entrySearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
                    SearchResultCollection results = entrySearch.FindAll();

                    ResultPropertyCollection rpc = results[0].Properties;
                    foreach (string rp in rpc.PropertyNames)
                    {
                        if (rp == "mobile")
                            Console.WriteLine(rpc["mobile"][0].ToString());

                        if(rp == "sAMAccountName")
                            Console.WriteLine(rpc["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString());
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace to query contact information from Active Directory because as you point out, they are not security principles. You'll need to read and parse the `member` property of the group directly from the group's `DirectoryEntry`. This will be a list of distinguished names of all the objects which are a member of the group. There's no way to know from this what kind of object they are so you'll need to query AD for each to find out.

You have all the code needed to accomplish this already in what you posted, just add the `member` property to the load list and then loop though it loading new `DirectoryEntry` objects. The `objectClass` property will tell you if it's a user, group or contact.

Comment: Hey, thank you. I used the DirectoryEntry and a searcher to find the group members, then loaded them on a new entry. Worked perfect.

Comment: @ThorsteinLøkensgard I'm glad it worked out. Please accept this answer :)